# not able to start android app in emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am not able to start my app in emulator. Following is the message by eclipse. What can be done ?

```
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] ------------------------------
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] Android Launch!
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] adb is running normally.
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] Performing com.asin.amit.AsinActivity activity launch
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-   5554' running compatible AVD 'Vid'
[2012-06-16 04:07:20 - Asin] Uploading Asin.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-06-16 04:07:26 - Asin] Installing Asin.apk...
[2012-06-16 04:07:27 - Asin] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2012-06-16 04:07:27 - Asin] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-06-16 04:07:27 - Asin] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: How big is this apk?  What does 'df' in the adb shell say about /data?   I do think I saw this error once spuriously (perhaps on a device) but it worked fine when I tried again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how to do this "What does 'df' in the adb shell say about /data?"  whole folder is 35mb. the app ran fine for few times and then it started showing this error.

Comment: 'adb shell df' seems like you've probably filled up the /data partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the Android emulator's memory capacity. There are 2 ways to do that,

1. Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" then go to "Run Configurations..." locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.
2. Go to Eclipse's Preferences, then Select "Launch" Add “-partition-size 1024” on the "Default emulator option" field, then click "Apply" and use your emulator as usual.

Comment: Why'd you try #2 after #1 worked for you, that's what I want to know :P.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try closing and restarting the emulator. If you're using the "save to snapshot"-feature, disable it on the next emulator-launch (i.e. don't choose "launch from snapshot")

2) Uninstall your app (if it has been successfully installed before) through the Settings-->"Applications" menu from within the emulator

3) Finally, if these don't help, increse the SD card-size of your emulator through the AVD-Manager settings